# Difference between 经常 and 时常?

Tags: meaning, usage, word

When do I use 经常 and 时常? Can they be used interchangeably? If there is difference between the two words, what situation do I use each of them?

Answer (score 1):

**No. They are not interchangeable at all.**

经常 bears more frequency than 时常. E.g. 我经常去看你 Vs. 我时常去看你. 我经常去看你 indicates I go see you more often than 我时常去看你.

If you say 我经常去打球，I'd think your frequency of playing ballgames is **high**. If you say 我时常去打球, I'd take that your frequency is normal/moderate (or probably a bit above normal), neither very high nor low.

Answer (score 0):

both 经常 and 时常 means 'often'

> 经 = regularly
>
> 常 = frequently
>
> 经常 = often (if you do something regularly and frequently, you do it often)

~

> 时= time
>
> 时常 = often (in time)

**You can use them interchangeably**

For Example:

经常遲到 = often late (emphasize the **regularity** of being late; being late is a regular behaviour for the subject)

时常遲到 = often late (emphasize the **frequency** of being late; the subject has been late many times)

经常不遵守规则 = often disobey the rule (disobey the rule is a regular behaviour for the subject)

时常不遵守规则 = often disobey the rule (the subject has disobeyed rule many times)

*Another term for 'often' is '常常' (reduplication of the adjective 常). It also emphasize the frequency*

Answer (score 0):

＂汉语同义词词典＂经常／时常［同］表示动作行为屡次发生。作状语。

［异］［经常］形容词。形容动作行为屡次发生。常作状语，可修饰用＂不＂否定的动词；也作谓语、定语。否定形式为＂不经常＂。可构成＂经常化＂、＂经常性＂。例：（１）我和新以经常同他开玩笑，他从不发脾气。（巴金＜一颗红心＞）（２）那时我们的宿营经常不在一起，我们几乎每天有演出任务。（丁玲＜她更是一个文学家＞）（３）那时刻印传单比较经常（吴伯萧＜无花果＞）（４）他们经常的下处，是木匠黎老东家。（孙犁＜铁木前传＞）（５）架上的书都摆得整整齐齐，看样子是不经常触动的。（陈玙＜夜幕下的哈尔滨＞）（６）为了使抗日宣传经常化，我们学校成立了＂中公剧社＂。（杜宣＜革命、戏剧，五十年生活片断＞）（７）广州三元里的农民队伍便是从临时自发的组织发展成为联系各村各乡的经常性组织的。（翦伯赞主编＜中国史纲要＞）

［时常］副词。表示动作行为屡次发生，不强调其一贯性。只作状语。常用其肯定形式，一般不修饰用＂不＂否定的动词。例（１）离开了北京，我是时常想念北京的。（徐迟＜山峡记＞）（２）故母时常闹脾气。她单在鸡蛋里找骨头（老舍＜我的母亲＞）（３）我时常想，小川是有作为的，有能力的。（孙犁＜伙伴的回忆＞）

［附］＂经常＇还表示平常的、日常的，如＂读抱是咱们生活里的经常事儿＂。

Comment: What is the point of answering in chinese to someone who is asking a basic question and thus has not the possibility of understanding the answer at all?